# Select from where in ( ) table?

Tags: abap, opensql

I want a select with dynamic `where` conditions in ABAP Syntax.

An SQL Statement would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MCH1 WHERE MATNR IN (...) AND CHARG IN (...)
```

My approach was to add 2 structures `ZMATN_STR` and `ZCHARG_STR` to the dictionary with associated components as line (`MATNR`, `CHARG`).
Then create 2 table types with associated line types.

Now im stucked in ABAP because I don't know how to write the `where` clause.
That's what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
 FROM
  mch1
  FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @matnrs
 WHERE
    matnr = @matnrs-matnr
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_result).
```

It works for either matnr or charg but not with both of them.

**Additional Info**

This select happens in a function module where 2 import parameter exists (the 2 table types) - so I cannot just write `where in ('xxx', 'yyy')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data lr_matnr type range of matnr.
data lr_charg type range of MCH1-charg.
"Fill lr_matnr and lr_charg...
SELECT * FROM MCH1 WHERE MATNR IN @lr_matnr AND CHARG IN @lr_charg
  INTO TABLE @data(lt_result).
```

Comment: Thanks - it works.
I really miss arrays in ABAP - it sometimes feels like you need way more code to get the same results as in other languages :D

Comment: @user9597084 Internal tables in ABAP *are* arrays for all intends and purposes. The classic syntax for them can be a bit awkward, especially when you are used to the style of the C syntax family programming languages. But there were some additions in recent releases that made them more convenient to use, like the `VALUE #( ( row )  ( row ) )` syntax to create them as literals and the `table[ n ]` syntax for accessing entries by index.